# How to read data.txt in main_file.exe without keeping them in single folder in python

Tags: python

py this will read text file which is placed in a same folder and i have created `main_file.spec` and `main_file.exe` files by using `pyinstaller --onefile main_File.py` ,the `main_file.exe` file is created in dist file. when i try to run `main_file.exe` application it is giving me error like unable to find specified file.

I tried modifying my `main_file.spec` by adding `datas= [('data.txt','.')]` but dint worked please help me out. Main question is i dont want to place `data.txt` and `main_file.exe` in single folder. When i run `main_file.exe` it should read `data.txt` file 
my `main_file.py`

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil

def main():
   d = os.getcwd()   #Gets the current working directory
   print(d)
   os.chdir("..")    #Go up one directory from working directory
   o = [os.path.join(d,o) for o in os.listdir(d) if 
   os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d,o))] # Gets all directories in the tuple
   print(o)
   for item in o:
       if os.path.exists(item + '\\data.txt'):
           file = item + '\\data.txt'
           input('Enetr any to read file')
           f = open(file)
           print(f.read())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
   input('Enter any key to close')
```

and my spec file for this

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Project_Main_File.py'],
             pathex=['E:\\Python coding\\File_Read'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Project_Main_File',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first of all- if you're trying to read the file `data.txt` but the file is named `main_file.spec` it will simply not find it, it's not the same file.
I would suggest if you want to read `data.txt` before converting to exe but `main_file.spec` after convertion- use `try: catch:` so it'll try to read the `data.txt` file but if it doesn't exist read `main_file.spec`.

Secondly- you don't have to place the files in the same folder but the relative path need to be exact always, btw I'm not sure you have to use os to use relative path but maybe it's just on python3.

If you want the files to be in neighbor folders you can do somthing like:

```py
filepath = "../data/main_file.spec" # one directory up, one down to data, and to the file

with open(filepath) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

That should be it, remember to place the files in the right relative path.
And with the try catch:

```py
filetxt = "../data/data.txt" # one directory up, one down to data, and to the file
filespec = "../data/main_file.spec" # one directory up, one down to data, and to the file

try:
    with open(filetxt) as f:
        print(f.read())
catch:
    with open(filespec) as f:
        print(f.read())
```

that should be it!